# problem running hello world with tornado web server (Python 2.5,Win 7)

Tags: python, ipv6, tornado

I am using Python 2.5 on Windows 7 (64bit).

I installed pycurl-7.15.5.1 (with win binaries) and tornado (using pip).

When I run the following hello world code:

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.write("Hello World!")

if __name__=='__main__':
    app = tornado.web.Application([(r"/",MainHandler),])
    application.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

I get the following error:-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "hello_tornado.py", line 11, in <module>
    application.listen(8888)
  File "c:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\tornado\web.py", line 1193, in listen
    server.listen(port, address)
  File "c:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\tornado\netutil.py", line 100, in listen
    sockets = bind_sockets(port, address=address)
  File "c:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\tornado\netutil.py", line 263, in bind_sockets
    sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IPV6, socket.IPV6_V6ONLY, 1)
  AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'IPV6_V6ONLY'
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `app.listen(8888)` instead of `application.listen(8888)`? `application` isn't instantiated anywhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tornado has some IPv6 confusion on windows apparently. You can fix it by specifiyig the IP you want it to listen on like this:

```
application.listen(8888,'127.0.0.1')
```

or maybe

```
application.listen(8888,'0.0.0.0')
```

Answer (score 0):

from tornado web page (http://www.tornadoweb.org/)

Platforms: Tornado should run on any Unix-like platform, although for the best performance and scalability only Linux and BSD (including BSD derivatives like Mac OS X) are recommended.

I think it is not compatible with windows

Things similar with tornado can be achieve with twisted framework http://twistedmatrix.com which works under windows

interesting pointers are

http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/web/howto/web-in-60/index.html

and

http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/web/howto/web-in-60/dynamic-content.html

Comment: It is compatible with windows. It runs ok on my win7.

Comment: @akaRem did you take any special steps to get it to work on windows 7 or did it work out of the box? what installation process did you follow?

Comment: @jonnieM If I can find here  http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ what I want to install, I always download installeers from here. I love this repository! Many thanks to crew of this lab! Everything works perfect.