# Django Contact Form Mail Error :Address family not supported by protocol Request

Tags: python, django

I am using Django for contact form in my  website
. I get problem when submit

```
[Errno 97] Address family not supported by protocol
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://site.com/accept
Django Version: 1.3.1
Exception Type: error
Exception Value:    
[Errno 97] Address family not supported by protocol
Exception Location: /usr/lib64/python2.6/socket.py in create_connection, line 567
Python Executable:  /usr/local/bin/python
Python Version: 2.6.6
```

Here is my settings:

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'

EMAIL_PORT = 587

EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'myemail@gmail.com'

EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'mypassword'

EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems this has nothing to do with your settings, but with your server configuration. Some services get confused with IPv6 (like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8549132/190887)). You should try to run either your web server and SMTP server by listening to an IPv4 address.

In 2014, the problem should be resolved, since libraries and frameworks have been updated and should be used to manipulate IPv6 addresses.