# sending gmail in python from remote server

Tags: python, smtp, gmail, remote-server

i am sending a gmail
i used this code

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import socket
import smtplib

gmail_user = 'username'
gmail_pwd = 'xxxxxx'
FROM = 'my@gmail.com'
TO = ['reciver1@gmail.com','reciver2@gmail.com']
a ="55"
SUBJECT = "this is my testing man" 
TEXT = "Testing sending mail using gmail servers"+a+"care full"
message = """\From: %s\nTo: %s\nSubject: %s\n\n%s
""" % (FROM, ", ".join(TO), SUBJECT, TEXT)
try:
    #server = smtplib.SMTP(SERVER) 
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587) #or port 465 doesn't seem to work!,587,'72.167.1.187'
    server.ehlo()
    server.starttls()
    server.login(gmail_user, gmail_pwd)
    server.sendmail(FROM, TO, message)
    #server.quit()
    server.close()
    print 'successfully sent the mail'
except Exception, error:
    print "Unable to send e-mail: '%s'." % str(error)
```

i am successfully sending mail from local system,

i run the same code in remote server i got this error

```
Unable to send e-mail: '(97, 'Address family not supported by protocol')'.
```

why this code is not working in remote server, please help me

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the computer you are running this script on does not like IPv6 addresses.

I would guess that the remote server only has an IPv6 address whereas your local system has a IPv4 address.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21941450), for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, u need to get into your gmail account before it can be sent to a recipient, to do so, you need to change your g-mail setting to accept logins from less secure apps (SMTP), that should fix your problem