# Tornado socket.error on ARM

Tags: python, tornado, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to run a small python webapp on a RasPi using the Tornado server, but whenever I try to start it, I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 78, in <module>
    application.listen(8080)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado-3.0.1-py2.7.egg/tornado/web.py", line 1343, in listen
    server.listen(port, address)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado-3.0.1-py2.7.egg/tornado/tcpserver.py", line 113, in listen
    sockets = bind_sockets(port, address=address)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado-3.0.1-py2.7.egg/tornado/netutil.py", line 69, in bind_sockets
    sock = socket.socket(af, socktype, proto)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 187, in __init__
    _sock = _realsocket(family, type, proto)
socket.error: [Errno 97] Address family not supported by protocol
```

I'm reasonably sure I did everything properly

- The port I'm attempting to listen on isn't otherwise in use
- I don't specify an address, but it doesn't seem I need to since the [Tornado "hello world"](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/#hello-world) doesn't either (That demo app itself doesn't run either; it gives exactly the same error with a different line number)
- The same app seemingly runs fine on x86 and x86_64 machines

Is there a different call I need to make on ARM, or is this a bug somewhere in tornado/socket.py? Is there a workaround available?

Since it seems to be relevant, the Pi is running the latest Raspbian image from [this page](http://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads) (downloaded from the second mirror a couple of days ago, so not *the* latest anymore). I'm currently trying out an older version, and will try out the latest if that doesn't work.

Comment: Does the "Tornado hello world" app run on your RasPi?

Comment: @Robᵩ - Just tried it; no, it gives me the same error.

Comment: It would be helpful if **socket.py** printed the *address family*.  I guess you use **Linux**?  This is most likely a kernel `.config` issue.  For instance, your Linux on the *Raspberry Pi* may not be configured with *Unix Domain* sockets.  I doubt this is ARM related.  Please provide information on the OS.

Comment: @artlessnoise - Done. I'm in the middle of a re-try with an older version of the image file.

Comment: Odd, **8080** is probably TCP/IP.  I would guess the kernel has that configuration.  Can you run a plain TCP/IP server; say the `iperf` package?  Then likely the issue is with *Tornado* and not your kernel.  Sorry, I didn't look closely at your trace.  The PC and ARM should both be little-endian; that is why I guess it is kernel `.config` based.

Comment: I have the same issue, my app works well on aws EC2 instance with ubuntu (`Ubuntu 13.04 (GNU/Linux 3.8.0-19-generic x86_64)`) and i got the same error on my Raspberry Pi (`Linux 3.6.11+ #371 PREEMPT Thu Feb 7 16:31:35 GMT 2013 armv6l`) my app worked before a dist-upgrade on my Raspb Pi, seems to be an error on the Kernel, not on tornado !

Comment: @artlessnoise `print family, type, proto` return `2 1 6`, 
`2 1 6` and
`10 1 6`

Comment: @artlessnoise - `iperf -s` seems to be able to listen to port `5001` successfully. Changing the port for my Tornado app to `5001` results in the same error, but with a different port number. How do I reconfigure kernel `.config` to use *Unix Domain* sockets?

Comment: **Family** 2==IPv4, 10==IPv6  **Proto** 6 is TCP.  Maybe the new kernel doesn't have IPv6. Maybe helpful [Tornado on Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7503039/problem-running-hello-world-with-tornado-web-server-python-2-5-win-7)?  Sorry, it is not *Unix Domains*; that was a guess.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This turns out to have nothing to do with ARM. As per [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8549132/190887) `artless noise` linked in one of his comments, it *looks* like Tornado gets confused if the system you start it up on supports IPv6, and this apparently includes the Raspberry Pi.

Starting the server up with

```
application.listen(8080, '0.0.0.0')
```

instead of just

```
application.listen(8080)
```

resolved the issue for me.

**EDIT2**: For cross-platform developers: the previous tactic I outlined actually doesn't work. Calling `application.listen` binds the specified port even if the call errors (which seems like it might be a bug in Tornado). In other words, you need to determine what do before invoking `listen`.

Since I run my app on GNU/Debian, the following worked well enough for me:

```
def listen(port):
    (osName, machineName, osRelease, osVersion, machineType) = os.uname()
    if re.search("arm", machineType):
        logging.info("Running on ARM...")
        application.listen(port, '0.0.0.0')
    else:
        logging.info("Running on x86...")
        application.listen(port)
```

No idea how reliable this solution is under other OSes or architectures.